# Update List view to specific item position

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am having a receiver that broadcast when a intent service finishes a server call,When receiver is broadcast in onReceive I have updated list view with new data. What I want is to set the position of item to last element in a list before the broadcast. I have tried using setSelection() and smoothScrollToPosition(),but the list is focused to first item every time a list is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where mAdapter is your Adapter Object which you used to populate data in ListView.it will only update your ListView without focused to first item.

Comment: I have used this code. but still every time list view focus to first item

Answer (score 2):

use notifyDataSetChanged() to update list view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code also

listview.requestLayout();
listview.setSelectionFromTop(listview.getLastVisiblePosition()-20,0);

This make Listview selection from bottom side item